# How can I limit the display to distinct records?

Tags: php, sql, php-5.3

As shown in the picture below, there are redundant records.  How can the redundancy be removed?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$YearNow=Date('Y');
include('../connection/connect.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentvotes,student where student.idno = studentvotes.idno");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
        <tr class="record" style="text-align:center;">
        <td><?php echo $row['idno']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['candid']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

[image: Here's the sample]

Comment: but then what would it display for the candid column if you want to display only one record?

Comment: If I got this I only want to display one idno and if I click it to the table then It will display like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Change your SQL To:

```
SELECT * FROM studentvotes,student where student.idno = studentvotes.idno 
GROUP BY student.idno
```

With `GROUP BY`, you specify a column (even multiple columns) to group with.

The results are grouped by those columns it means those columns (combinations if multiple) will come only once in the result set.

For example, your table has multiple entries of `iDno`.

When we fire SELECT query, it will return all rows having multiple instances of `iDno`.

If we apply `GROUP BY`, it will return results grouped by `iDno`.

Comment: @renishkhunt, please read my answer carefully. I have added explanation. I can delete my answer if you think I have copied you.

Comment: and also pupil i got a new knowledge after reading your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just add groupby to your query like

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM 
                        studentvotes,student 
                        where student.idno = studentvotes.idno 
                        GROUP BY student.idno
                      ");
```

for more details please read @pupil Answer.

i hope this is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for not displaying redundant records.

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
             FROM   studentvotes, 
             student 
             WHERE  student.idno = studentvotes.idno 
             GROUP  BY student.idno
");
```